# Sum of positive operators. Each must be proportional to right hand side

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-information, hilbert-space

In [these](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf) notes, on page 13, there is a claim:

> we have $$
> \sum_{\mu, a} N_\mu M_a |\psi \rangle \langle \psi|M_a^\dagger N_\mu^\dagger = |\psi \rangle  \langle \psi|.
> $$ Since the left-hand side is a sum of positive operators, the equation can only hold if each of these terms is proportional to $|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|$, hence $$ N_\mu M_a = \lambda_{\mu a} I. $$

I do not understand how it follows from positivity (and the form of the terms) that they are all proportional to the RHS.

Comment: Hint: What happens if you apply each side to a state orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$

Comment: @BySymmetry you get 0 on RHS and on left-hand side sum of $| \langle v|N_\mu M_a |\psi \rangle |^2$ terms which are all $\geq 0$ so that they each must be zero.  Therefore, $|v \rangle$ is orthogonal to $N_\mu M_a |\psi \rangle$ for each $\mu, a$ and since $|v \rangle$ was any orthogonal state it implies that $N_\mu M_a |\psi \rangle$ is proportional to $|\psi \rangle$. Is this correct? Also, I think that positivity is implicitly used due to the form of the LHS terms but that it itself is not enough. Is this true? Thank you for the hint.